# IOS Storyboard Constraining Every Subview to bottom of screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

This seems like it should be very simple, but I am having a terrible time trying to get every subview (they act like menu bars) constrained to the bottom of the parent view in the IOS storyboard.

There seems to be automatic constraints placed between the subviews that make them override the constraint I'm trying to set. I try to take these off, and then place the new constraints, but nothing seem to work as I loop over trying to reset constraints, over and over and over...

It should be very simple, set all of the uiviews to a particular width and length and set the distance between the bottom of the superview to be equal to 0. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to happy constraint editing in interface builder is simple:

- Don't do it

If that isn't possible, then:

- Create your own constraints *before* trying to delete the system ones
- Make judicious use of the pinning menu and editing constraints in the inspector
- **Don't drag and drop your views after you've added them** - this causes interface builder to discard *all* constraints and set you up with a new set of "best guess" system constraints.

I've written more about this [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/) but that's the gist of it.